# @Value not resolving using <context:property-placeholder location=" />

Tags: spring

Hey guys I have a problem.  I'm using Spring and I have a class with an injected boolean

```
    protected boolean ignoreVisibleFlag;
```

I have verified that indeed that property lives in my properties file:

and I have verified that I have this in my Application Context XML:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath.properties" />
```

However I still get the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value 
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:77)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using Spring 4.1.7.RELEASE

Comment: tried to inject the property into a `String` and then convert it to `boolean` afterwards? it's a bit dirty workaround, but i think it can do the trick

Comment: Can you try with Boolean instead of boolean primitive i.e., `protected Boolean  ignoreVisibleFlag;`

Comment: Let me guess, you are using component scanning and have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` and the `<context:property-placeholder />` is only in 1 of them.

Comment: M. Deinum's fix worked.

Answer (score 1):

From past experience using primitive wasn't able to handle the casting from string (as read) to boolean.

What you need to do is use Object instead of the primitive which will enable the conversion process from String to boolean.

```
@Value("${mojo.ignoreAlertsVisibleFlag}")
protected Boolean ignoreVisibleFlag;
```

Comment: That isn't the issue, as you can see from the stack trace... The `${..}` isn't resolved and this is due to the lack of a `PlaceholderConfigurer` of some sort.

Comment: @M.Deinum yep missed that bit like script kiddie. Good pick up mate

Answer (score 0):

M. Deinum's fix worked.  I needed to add the  to my dispatcher servlet.